# Como mostrar varios valores en la misma celda de un datatable

Tags: datatables

Estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar varios valores de distintos campos de la base de datos en la datatable. El código que tengo de la tabla es:

```
var listar = function () {
var table = $('#customers-table-view').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    ajax: {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'listar'
    },
    columns: [
        {'data': 'customer_code'},
        {'data': 'tax_number'},
        {'data': 'company_name'},
        {'data': 'city'},
        {'data': 'state'},
        {'data': 'service1'},
        {"defaultContent": $botones}
    ],
```

En la base de datos tengo service1, service2, service3... a on o a off. Lo que me gustaría es conseguir esos valores en la misma columna. Es decir que en la celda quedase algo así como; On, Off, Off... 
Luego ya renderizaré el on y el off 
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado la solución al problema. O más bien me han ayudado en SO en inglés. La comparto aquí para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda encontrar la solución.

```
$('#customers-table-view').DataTable({
columns: [
...
{ 
  data: 'servicios',
  render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    return row.service1 + ', ' + row.service2 + ', ' + row.service3
  }
},
...
```

]
});

Un saludo.

Comment: Esta bueno, lo único es que no busca en los concatenados, por ejemplo yo junte el nombre y el apellido de un usuario pero no podía buscar por apellido, solo por nombre. Aun así muchas gracias, esto puede ser muy útil

Comment: Olvidenlo, ya pude hacer que busque xd